# Change the html text using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I want to replace the text "updated cover photo" with "updated deras omslagsfoto" using jquery. I have below mention html code. I see this code after inspecting the page. This text is fetched from Facebook. There is no direct access to change this text. You can check the Facebook feed in the fourth column by visiting the URL: visbyhemtjanst.se

```
<p class="wff-post-text" style="  "><a class="wff-link-tab" href="http://facebook.com/1100591156696075" style="color: indigo;" target="_blank">Visby hemtjänst</a> updated cover photo.</p>
```

I have tried this:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    var myString = '<p class="wff-post-text" style="  "><a class="wff-link-tab" href=" " style="color: indigo;" target="_blank">Visby hemtjänst</a> cover photo.</p>';
    var myArray = myString.split('>');

     //$(".wff-post-text").html(myArray);

     for(var i=0;i<myArray.length;i++){
        $(".wff-post-text").append("<p>arr["+i+"] =>"+myArray[i]+"</p>").replaceWith("updated deras omslagsfoto");

    }
});
</script>

<p class="wff-post-text" style="  "><a class="wff-link-tab" href="http://facebook.com/1100591156696075"
style="color: indigo;" target="_blank">Visby hemtjänst</a> updated deras omslagsfoto</p>

</html>
```

When I inspect this script I do not see entire `<p>` tag. My expected output when I inspect the page is:

```
<p class="wff-post-text" style="  "><a class="wff-link-tab" href="http://facebook.com/1100591156696075" style="color: indigo;" target="_blank">Visby hemtjänst</a> updated cover photo.</p>
```

I think need to concatenate the html element and jquery array values.

Comment: sorry...didnt understand your problem.

Comment: please check the website  visbyhemtjanst.se . there is English text "updated cover photo" i want to change this

Comment: Try with $(".wff-link-tab").text('updated deras omslagsfoto');

Comment: @RahulPatel:  i have tried this. it is working bt i want entire <p> tag in output so how to insert this text in <p> tag.

Comment: All you want is to replace the "updated cover photo" text with "updated deras omslagsfoto" right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested directly on your website:

```
jQuery("p:contains('updated their cover photo.')")
.contents()
.filter(function() { 
    return this.nodeType ==3; 
}).replaceWith(' updated deras omslagsfoto')
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: contains is a jquery filter used to find text directly on the HTML. So with this line, I found the "p" element that is parent of the facebook "a" element. with that element selected, i can filter its text excluding the text withing the "a" link and change what is written.

that way, you can change the "update cover photo" text without changing the "Visby hemtjänst" link

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_nodetype.asp

Comment: Thank you. like the explanation

Answer (score 0):

Using `var ExistingHTML = $(".wff-link-tab")[0].outerHTML;` you can get entire `<a>` tag and then append it with "updated deras omslagsfoto" message and place it in `<p>` tag HTML using `$(".wff-post-text").html(ExistingHTML+' updated deras omslagsfoto')`.

Please check below snippet. you will get better idea.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var ExistingHTML = $(".wff-link-tab")[0].outerHTML;
  $(".wff-post-text").html(ExistingHTML+' updated deras omslagsfoto'); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="wff-post-text" style="  "><a class="wff-link-tab" href="http://facebook.com/1100591156696075" style="color: indigo;" target="_blank">Visby hemtjänst</a> updated cover photo.</p>
```

Comment: @Rashmi Sonke So in this way only text of <p> tag will changed all other thing will be as it is.